# Good Open Source Code to learn Web Programming

Tags: web-applications, open-source

Hi can someone point me to some Good Open Source Code to learn Web Programming (Language doesn't matter).

i'm looking for source code of web-applications not frameworks

I'm not a beginner, I can code to some extent. I want to know how stuffs are done in real world applications.

Comment: You can get good software with open-source torrent clients. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to study the code of popular open source web applications to understand how 'real world, live, popular' applications are coded.

If that is so, I recommend the following popular, open source applications:

- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) - coded with PHP, this application is a very popular blog management system
- [Text Pattern](http://textpattern.com) - coded with PHP, this application is similar to wordpress but slightly more advanced.
- [CGI Module](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm) - coded with Perl, this perl module is used in most perl based web applications. Understanding the code of this module will give you great insights on a part of how the internet works.
- [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org) - coded with Python, is a popular application in the python community to interface / interact with databases.

It would be easier if you familiarize yourself with one of these languages well before you try to understand the working of any of the above.

Comment: wordpress would really not be on my list, unless you want to learn how not to do it...

Comment: http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/03/wordpress_is_a_bad_joke/

Comment: You are right about WordPress, it is not very well coded. The WordPress team are making an effort to improve it though. (I am not a fan of WordPress and prefer TextPattern, but one can't deny that Wordpress is the most popular blog management system out there).

Comment: just that popularity does not necessarily correlate with code quality!

Comment: joomla 1.0 was by far the most popular CMS ever but the code quality is between horrible and acceptable. This is not true for 1.5 which is a real improvement in that regard.

Comment: Agreed - it's a sorry state of affairs when quality and popularity are not directly proportional.

Comment: It's a rather *normal* state of affairs, really.  Looking at the internet as a whole, you'd never guess that 2/3 of it is held together with duct tape and twine.  People care that they click and stuff happens; the code behind it is (quite rightly) not their main concern.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this question is a bit vague.  Are you looking for open source web frameworks, or open source code written in web frameworks  But try looking at [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [ASP.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/), [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org), [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal), and [Wordpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordpress) among many, many others.

A couple more apps (now that this is clarified) are [Gitweb](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb) and [Meldware](http://www.buni.org/mediawiki/index.php/Meldware_Communications_Suite)

Comment: i'm looking for source code of web-applications not frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Learning by reading the source code of an open source application always *seemed* like a good idea, but every time I tried it, it was a futile effort.  I think that's because there's three general types of open source apps, and none are good to read for learning's sake:

1. **The small projects.**  By small, I mean "almost not a project" small.  For one reason or another, these never made it past the proof of concept phase.  Either the ideas weren't interesting enough, or worse, the programmer(s) weren't good enough to translate it into a ready-for-prime-time app.  Often, the ability of these programmers aren't significantly greater than your current level, so these aren't worth your time studying.
2. **The medium-small projects**.  These projects are big enough to be interesting and sophisticated, but the publicly-available technical documentation is severely lacking and you'll never make heads or tails of their architecture.  You could email the contributors, but they're probably too busy dividing their time between a high-level paid day job and committing all their personal time to this pet project.  Moving on...
3. **The big time projects.**  E.g. Firefox, Eclipse, etc.  Software in this category is meticulously documented, but it doesn't matter, because the amount of time required to read and understand it all is prohibitive.  You'd have to be mad to put yourself through that unless you're working on the project (and hopefully getting paid to do it!).

I don't mean to dissuade you, this is just my personal experience.  If you want to become a better programmer, focus on finding a job.  The pace of learning during my first year on the job was orders of magnitude greater than any work I did on my own.

Comment: Find a job or just start to write your own code. I recall there was some nice article by Joel Spolsky related to learning-by-writing-code-yourself, but I cannot find it now (maybe you will: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/). If you try to solve problems by yourself, you will learn a lot more than when you see the solution without knowing why it evolved to that form. Just write some code, read articles written by some smart guys, and you will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice first to choose a language or a platform. For example groovy on grails.
Then take tutorials. Every platform have a "petshop example" or something like that where you can start and follow.

If language doens't matter try Mhonarc which is written in perl.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Python, you can look at [Reddit](http://reddit.com/code/) or the [Django source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/). I know Django's a web framework but the code is really well done.

Answer (score 0):

The most advanced PHP framework I've seen, with the beautiful code: [FLOW3](http://flow3.typo3.org/)
Yet my answer is only relevant, if you are looking for serious framework as the code example, and do know the basics already...

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://www.asp.net and http://www.asp.net/community/projects/ for big open source web projects
http://www.codeproject.com/ for smaller examples
And http://code.google.com/opensource/ for a very big list
And Also http://www.codeplex.com/ , http://sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at [Pier](http://www.piercms.com/) It is a content management system written in Seaside. It is much better structured than any of the other suggestions I've seen here.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to learn from abc then w3schools.com is a better option.

Where you can find lots of seciton like asp,asp.net, HTML etc. Also you will have lots of
examples there.

Comment: I'm not a beginner, I can code to some extent. I want to know how stuffs are done in real world applications.